# await continues before iprocess finishes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am have created a custom factory that runs X number of threads.  My problem is that I would like my ContinueWiths finish before executing the code after my await.

CALLING CODE:

```
Task t = _manager.RunCalcsCustomFactory(int.Parse(textTasksToCreate.Text), int.Parse(textMaxThreads.Text), cancelSource.Token, new Progress<string>(UpdateStatus), new Progress<int>(UpdateProgress));

Task errorHandlingTask = t.ContinueWith((tt) => ProcessError(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
Task cancelTask = t.ContinueWith((tttt) => TasksComplete(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
await Task.WhenAll(t);

UpdateStatus("Done");
```

Within my tasks I throw an error right away.  So I want my ProcessError to finish before `UpdateStatus("Done")` is executed.

Here is my output:

```
start thread10
Waiting for tasks to finish.
Exception: Too many connections open.
Done
Error: Too many connections open.
ERROR
```

Notice the done if displayed before the `UpdateStatus("Error: Too many connections open.")` in the RunCalcsCustomFactory and `UpdateStatus("ERROR")` is ran in ProcessError.

I want `UpdateStatus("Done")` ran after the call back from RunCalcsCustomFactory is finished and ProcessError is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you have `ContinueWith` in your code, you should just be using `async`/`await` instead:

```
try
{
  await _manager.RunCalcsCustomFactory(int.Parse(textTasksToCreate.Text), int.Parse(textMaxThreads.Text), cancelSource.Token, new Progress<string>(UpdateStatus), new Progress<int>(UpdateProgress));
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
  TasksComplete();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  ProcessError();
}

UpdateStatus("Done");
```

Comment: Wasn't I doing that with await Task.WhenAll(t);

Comment: @MatimalND: You were only `await`ing one task, not its continuations.

Comment: I originally had my code as you suggested but my call back to UpdateStatus("Exception: Too many connections open.
"); did not update the UI before the UpdateStatus("Done") updated the UI.  Same outcome.

Comment: @MatimalND: OK, I see your problem now. It's actually because `IProgress<T>.Report` is asynchronous. You may want to use Rx in this scenario; I have an [`ObservableProgress` that you could use as a starting point](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/4248e50b4cb52b933c0d). Or, you could report exceptions by... throwing an exception, instead of calling `IProgress<T>.Report`.

Comment: I see you are smarter then me.  The error was just one example.  I was trying to simplfy the question.  I also have 'IProgress<T>.Report' in my xTasks that I create.  so I get the Done in my output before "Task x complete" is displayed in the status.  So in my mind the task is not done but the 'AWAIT' finishes.  I can catch the exception but was just curious on a SIMPLE way to truly wait tell all tasks finish updating the ui.

Comment: Another example. Clone Count: 2  Current Thread: 17 Seconds: 9:31:30 AM
Done
Clone Count: 1  Current Thread: 18 Seconds: 9:31:30 AM
Elapsed Time: 48461

Comment: @MatimalND: If you are willing to just drop the "excess" progress reports, then a simple boolean `isRunning` variable should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  That was a option I was going to use just have property I set in my class on start then on completion/cancelation/error I clear and wait for that to be clear before continuing on.  I was just curious on why the tasks are not really finished before the await finished.  PS, some of your other post got me this far.  Thanks again and have a great day!